# how to disable dates before today in jQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

How do I disable dates before today in jQuery datepicker **WITHOUT using `minDate: 0`**?

I would like to enable navigation of the calendar as per usual before today while making sure that user do NOT pick dates before today.

(i.e. say today's date is 11Aug11 and I would like all the dates before this disabled but still enabling user to go to previous months, years, etc.)

Comment: From a UX perspective, why would you want them to be able to *see* the values without being able to *select* the values?

Comment: Thanks guys, I do agree it does seem redundant but I'm building a website that allows client to arrange meetings/events. It might be more convenient for the client to be able to have a look back on previous dates on the same calendar just in case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I agree that it's weird behavior, you might be able to fake it using the [`onSelect`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect)  event of the datepicker.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Date').datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            //Get today's date at midnight
            var today = new Date();
            today = Date.parse(today.getMonth()+1+'/'+today.getDate()+'/'+today.getFullYear());
            //Get the selected date (also at midnight)
            var selDate = Date.parse(dateText);

            if(selDate < today) {
                //If the selected date was before today, continue to show the datepicker
                $('#Date').val('');
                $(inst).datepicker('show');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Basically, you handle the `onSelect` event.

When a date is selected, check to see if it's before today's date.

If it *is*, then you immediately [show](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-show) the datepicker again and clear out the input box attached to it.

---

**Updated**
Code sample is now completely functional.  Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antelopelovefan/ZW7cs/34/) to demonstrate.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this is still helpful to someone.
My solution is to place checks on individual dates like this:

```
$("#StartDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',  beforeShowDay: NotBeforeToday});



function NotBeforeToday(date)
{
    var now = new Date();//this gets the current date and time
    if (date.getFullYear() == now.getFullYear() && date.getMonth() == now.getMonth() && date.getDate() > now.getDate())
        return [true];
    if (date.getFullYear() >= now.getFullYear() && date.getMonth() > now.getMonth())
       return [true];
     if (date.getFullYear() > now.getFullYear())
       return [true];
    return [false];
}
```

I find it simple and elegant

Answer (score 2):

simplest solution could....

```
<script type="text/javascript">$('#date').datepicker({ minDate: 0 });</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear to be configurable. At [line 1434 of jquery.ui.datepicker.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js#L1434), if a `maxDate` is specified, it sets a `maxDraw` variable and draws up to the month of that date, without regard for any other flags.

But I also agree with zzzzBov. Why would the user need to see values they can't select?

Answer (score 1):

Instead you can write a function in your .js file like this-

```
$(function () {

             var date = new Date();
             var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
             var currentDate = date.getDate();
             var currentYear = date.getFullYear();

            if($("#dateToSelect").length > 0){
                $("#dateToSelect").datepicker({
                 maxDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate)
             });
            }
})
```

Here "dateToSelect" is the id of the field where the date is shown. The checking of the date length here is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply write like this

```
$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
      format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
      minDate: Date()
})
```